# Issues printing with Canon Pixma Pro 100 - paper size

Tags: canon, printing

I've had this printer for years and I've never been able to print anything right. This is so frustrating. I've taken another attempt at figuring it out. After replacing all the inks (even though they were barely used) it is now complaining about paper size. As far as I can tell 11 blinks = wrong paper size.

I've selected A3, my paper size is 11" x 17" and put it into the top tray. I've selected A3 from Mac photo preview app. I've also tried printing from photoshop but I end up at the same paper size dialog. I am putting the paper in top tray so the long side is sticking up vertically, as it looks like the only way it could fit. I'm running out of ideas. I'm so frustrated with this printer.

Paper size options available:

[image]

**Update** After the comment below I've edited the "custom sizes" section and added 11x17. It seems to be printing now. Thank you.. I will post my progress

Comment: I think you're saying the printer is complaining about paper size. Have you tried selecting 11x17 inch paper?  (3rd in the list)   A3 is 11.69x16.53 inches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A3 paper is 11.69 x 16.53 inches. When you select A3 with 11x17 paper in it the printer is detecting the width of the paper and telling you that it is not the size you have indicated.

If you are using 11x17 inch paper, you need to select *11x17 inches* as your paper size.

Comment: It never gives you the option to select 11x17 paper

Comment: If you go to Photo Layout Print and stay away from My Image Garden, then you can select the 11x17 print size. This is a very stupid software and not at all what was promised when I did my research. I wish I had stayed away from the Canon series altogether. Tons of headaches to use this printer. Canon Pixma Pro-10